# How to select Document Mode in Chrome and Edge browsers similar to Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am working on converting a web page that was creating using old web standards to support modern web browsers.
The web page currently renders correctly in Internet Explorer, only after setting the Emulation >> Document mode to '5' as shown in the below attachment. Internet Explorer is going to be disabled soon.
On the modern browsers like Chrome and Edge, UI components are overlapping.

[image]

How to select Document Mode in chrome and Edge, couldn't find any option, please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that is not possible but you can install different chrome probably. But there is no option within DevTool for sure.

Comment: Can you please let me know, if there is any other version of chrome which supports document mode. Or else, is there any other latest browser supports Document Mode?

Comment: There is no browser other than IE which can emulate IE5. and if your goal is to update the page for modern web standards then you shouldn't want the browser to emulate IE5.

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to emulate IE 5 in Edge and Chrome's F12 devtools. If you want to  use IE 5 document mode, you can use Edge IE mode.

Can you use group policy? If yes, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies) to configure IE mode Compatibility mode to IE5 for the sites you want. The steps are like below:

1. [Enable Internet Explorer integration using Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#enable-internet-explorer-integration-using-group-policy)
2. [Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies#configure-using-the-configure-the-enterprise-mode-site-list-policy)

For how to create the Enterprise Mode Site List, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/add-multiple-sites-to-enterprise-mode-site-list-using-the-version-2-schema-and-enterprise-mode-tool). To load the site in IE5 Compatibility mode in Edge IE mode, the sample sites list file is like below:

```
<site-list version="4">
   <created-by>
     <tool>EMIESiteListManager</tool>
     <version>12.0.0.0</version>
     <date-created>04/12/2022 06:53:26</date-created>
   </created-by>
   <site url="www.somesite.com">
     <compat-mode>IE5</compat-mode>
     <open-in>IE11</open-in>
   </site>
</site-list>
```